ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE in all browsers on Ubuntu 22.04
I have dual boot of Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows, and after upgrading Ubuntu some websites stopped loading in all browsers. But everything is fine on Windows.
Tried using the ping command:
ping www.w3schools.com
PING cs837.wac.edgecastcdn.net (192.229.133.221) 56(84) bytes of data.
From mari-HP (192.139.0.112) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From mari-HP (192.139.0.112) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From mari-HP (192.139.0.112) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From mari-HP (192.139.0.112) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- cs837.wac.edgecastcdn.net ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +9 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4006ms
pipe 3

Also I saw how adding these lines to resolf.conf solved the problem.
But it didn`t work for me.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

traceroute showed this output, but I am new to Ubuntu and can`t quite figure it out.
traceroute www.w3schools.com
traceroute to www.w3schools.com (192.229.133.221), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  mari-HP (192.161.1.1)  3064.151 ms !H  3064.086 ms !H  3064.076 ms !H

Does onyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
*I am using a wired connection.

The output of ip route:
$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.0.0.0/8 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.111 metric 100
192.0.0.0/8 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.110 metric 600


To me, this really does look more like a routing issue than a DNS (name resolution) issue. The output of ip route might be helpful.

Let's do some debugging.  Can you ping 8.8.8.8?  Can you ping anywhere?  It's clear DNS works, but it's also clear something in your network upstream from you is blocking connectivity to the Internet.  What's the output of ip route?  Is your system DHCP or Static set?

The website you ping can block linux connections.

@Mahler  Can you explain what that means?
Because, my friend doesn`t have this problem with her Ubuntu. I got confused.

I know that server can detect os installed on your computer. If your friend doesn't have this problem, I think it's not your case.

You may want to try installing Opera web browser and use the VNP feature.

According to myip.ms The correct ip address for www.w3schools.com is 13.248.240.135
Put 13.248.240.135 in the URL of your web browser.

That just does a 301 redirect to w3schools.com, and if OP's DNS is not able to resolve then that won't change the problem.

@ThomasWard Whats really strange is even on my system traceroute www.w3schools.com reports a 192 address

And also https://traceroute-online.com/

probably because they use a global proxy system and CDN from EdgeCast to cache, etc. their content.  So 13.248.240.135 is going to be incorrect.  "Destination Host Unreachable" sounds more like there's a broken component in the w3schools system and proxy chain that is geo-related.

The result is the same:
This site can't be reached
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

@Mari Please run ip route and Edit your question to include this information.
